# python function returns nonetype, but i can convert it to string and its not null

Tags: python-2.7

So basically a class has been imported and and a function called from it. The called function is supposed to return a float, but when I perform addition on it it says cannot add type float and NoneType.

Yet I can convert the returned value to string and print it so it cant be null. I though NoneType was null or no value returned.

Calling function

```
    def showPositions(self):
         runningprofit = float(0)
         for trade in self.trades:
         #self.output.log("what does this show?" + str(trade.showTrade()))
         runningprofit += trade.showTrade()
```

Called function

```
def showTrade(self):
    tradeStatus = "Entry Price: "+str(self.entryPrice)+"\tStatus: "+str(self.status)+"\tExit Price: "+str(self.exitPrice)

    if (self.status == "CLOSED"):
        tradeStatus = tradeStatus + "\tProfit: "
        if (self.exitPrice > self.entryPrice):
            tradeStatus = tradeStatus + "\033[92m"
        else:
            tradeStatus = tradeStatus + "\033[91m"



        tradeStatus = tradeStatus+str(self.exitPrice - self.entryPrice)+"\033[0m"
        self.output.log(tradeStatus)
        return(float(self.exitPrice - self.entryPrice))
```

And the returned error is:

```
runningprofit += trade.showTrade()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Check your indentation; `showTrade` doesn't always execute a `return` statement as posted here.

Comment: *Anything* can be converted to a string and printed, including `None`.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was to do with the indent. I wasn't returning anything outside of if (self.status == "CLOSED"):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because the following condition is `False`:

```
if (self.status == "CLOSED"):
```

then, there is no branch which returns proper value and hence `None` is returned.

`None` can not be added to a `Float` therefore you are getting the error.

Your options are either to handle all the non-`CLOSED` statuses within `showTrade()` or handle `None` in `showPositions()`.